# SoapUI and Excel: empty values vs. no value

Tags: xpath, soapui

I am using SoapUI Pro 4.5.2 to read data from spreadsheets, put them into Soap requests to my web service, and get responses back to write to a spreadsheet.  It's working.

I have two fields in the input data pertinent to my question:

Middle name is defined as a string of 4 characters, and as minOccurs = 1 and maxOccurs = 1.

Postal extension code (the 4-digit number that is optional after the normal 5-digit code) is defined as a string of 4 digits.  This field is optional, so it is marked as minOccurs=0 and maxOccurs=1.

When I use the SoapUI UI interface to send a request, this works fine; if there's no value for middle name, SoapUI generates an empty tag and sends it (I guess because of the minOccurs=1).  If there's no value for PostalCode, it does not send any tag at all (I guess because of minOccurs=0).

When SoapUI reads data from an Excel spreadsheet, however, the response to the same data is an error indicating that the extended postal code value of '' is not legal, because it must be 4 digits.  It appears that SoapUI generates an empty tag for the extended postal code when reading data from the spreadsheet, and sends it.

I found the "Remove Empty Content" option for SoapUI requests, default to false. I set it to true, and now get an error back from validation indicating that middle name is required but not found.  I'm guessing that the remove empty content removed all the empty content (reasonable enough), and middle name has to be there, even if empty, because of the minOccurs=1.

Do I have any way out of this tail-chasing problem?  I suppose I'm looking for something like a conditional for the output of the postal extension code, so I can eliminate it if it's empty, even if reading values from the spreadsheet.

I am also curious if there are XSD fixes, but I greatly prefer a fix that doesn't involve changing the XSD -- that becomes a political matter.

EDIT FOR DETAIL:

To put input into the request: I have used the SoapUI UI to choose "properties" from the input spreadsheet for each of the input fields; when that's done, one ends up with values in the request fields like:

${SpreadsheetInput#FrstNm}

Where SpreadsheetInput is the name of the datasource step reading the spreadsheet, and FrstNm is one of the properties.  I do this with the "Get Data" option off the popup menu you get by right-clicking the request input field, but there may be other ways.

Comment: "read data from spreadsheets, put them into Soap requests" <- need moar detail! How exactly are you putting them into the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first your problem:

Remember that internally to SoapUI *almost* everything is a string. Doing something like:

```
<postCode>${SpreadsheetInput#PostCode}</postCode>
```

in your SOAP request, assuming PostCode is either blank or does not exist outright, will expand to:

```
<postCode></postCode>
```

and SoapUI will even optimize it to:

```
</postCode>
```

Then your validation kicks in, which says you do not need to provide this element, but if you do, it had better be 4-characters long. Which the above fails.

The solution:

You need to pragmatically (meaning you will have to write Groovy code) create this node in your request. There are several ways to handle this. The quick and dirty is with a Groovy step, that goes something like:

```
def postCode = context.expand('${SpreadsheetInput#PostCode}').trim()
if (postCode != null && postCode != '')
    testRunner.testCase.setpropertyValue("postCodeNode", "<postCode>" + postCode + "</postCode>")
else
    testRunner.testCase.setpropertyValue("postCodeNode", "")
```

Then in your request replace the original:

```
<postCode>${SpreadsheetInput#PostCode}</postCode>
```

with just:

```
${#TestCase#postCodeNode}
```

Notice, the XML node elements are part of the SoapUI property! Again: everything in SoapUI is just a plain string.

If you want something more hard-core, have a look at 
[dynamically create elements in a SoapUI request](https://siking.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/dynamically-create-elements-in-a-soapui-request/). This is mine.

Comment: Thanks, it appears you've answered my question.  You've used an || operator where you might mean && ?  (postCode would have to be both non-null and non-empty to put in the tags.)  I'm also not sure what "testCase" is in this context; is the only use of that to correspond to the "${testCase#postCodeNode}" in the property value?  And do I have to do this separately for each field, or is there a way to make a general-purpose null-and-empty tester and 'call' it from each field, passing parameters?

Comment: You are right about the `&&`! `testRunner.testCase` is a property that I meant; I was typing up the answer from memory ... which is not so good anymore. As for the general purpose tester: there are several different ways of doing it. Depends if you have the -Pro license, or just the free version. In the free you will just have to script it. In the -Pro you could do it with a script that lives in your script library http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/scripting-and-the-script-library.html , or an event handler: http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/custom-event-handlers.html

Comment: Pro version -- I'll take a look at this at work tomorrow, and accept the answer there.  thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.  If I return "boo" instead of "", it puts "boo" (w/out quotes) inside the postal code tags.  If my postal extension code has a value, I get my tags output within postal code tags.  It is as if the request step puts tags around whatever is returned by the script, instead of replacing the tags and text with the value returned by the script.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Can you join me in a chat about it?  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/82619/soapui-and-scripting?tab=general

Comment: Ok, for anyone who digs into this saga: SiKing's' excellent information includes the instruction "replace <tag>valueExpression</tag>" with "${#TestCase#postCodeNode}".  The thing I didn't understand about that is that you must replace that in the XML; my original expression was put on the "Form" view of the request, but putting the replacement expression there won't work.  (also: "#TestCase" is some kind of global used by Groovy in SoapUI and applies to your case as well; "#postCodeNode" is the variable you set to your desired value in your Groovy script.)